# Deserialize XML document, keeping track of order

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I am parsing an XML document using the XMLSerialization tool.  The sample XML file consists of `paragraphs` (`string`) and `tables`, which are a complex XML type.  `Tables` consist of a series of `row`, which consists of a series of `entry` (`string`)

I need to keep track of the position of each `table`, relative to each `paragraph`.  Is there a way of catching the position of each `table` as it is being parsed by the XMLSerialization tool? Or do I need to use a construct like `[XMLAnyElement]` and parse each `paragraph` and `table` sequentially in order to track the `table` position?  I would prefer to avoid that approach, because my real XML files have many levels that would need manual parsing. I have a feeling that I am missing something really obvious here, but I've been scouring SO and trying multiple approaches, but with no straightforward solution.

Here is my basic code:

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace XMLDeserializeTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string file = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\test.xml";

            test testClass = Deserialize(file);

        }

        static test Deserialize(string url)
        {
                XmlSerializer reader =
                    new XmlSerializer(typeof(test));
                StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(url);
                return reader.Deserialize(stream) as test;         
        }

    }

    public class test
    {
        [XmlElement("paragraph")]
        public List<string> paragraphs { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("table")]
        public List<Table> tables { get; set; }

        public test()
        {

        }

    }

    public class Table
    {
        [XmlElement("row")]
        public List<Row> rows { get; set; }

        public int nodeNumber { get; set; }  // This is what needs to be tracked

        public Table()
        {

        }
    }

    public class Row
    {
        [XmlElement("entry")]
        public List<string> entries { get; set; }

        public Row()
        {

        }
    }
```

My sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<test>
  <paragraph>Here is some text.</paragraph>
  <paragraph>Here is some more text. The table follows this paragraph.</paragraph>
  <table>
       <row>
          <entry>1</entry>
          <entry>2</entry>
          <entry>3</entry>
        </row>
        <row>
          <entry>4</entry>
          <entry>5</entry>
          <entry>6</entry>
        </row>
  </table>
  <paragraph>This is the last paragraph.  This comes after the table.</paragraph>  
</test>
```

I came up with one solution, using XDocument, but it seems pretty clumsy:

```
XDocument Xdoc = XDocument.Load(file);                 
int numParagraphs = 0;
int tableNumber = 0;
foreach(XElement item in Xdoc.Root.Descendants())
   {
      if (item.Name.LocalName.Equals("paragraph"))

   {
        numParagraphs++;
   }
      else if (item.Name.LocalName.Equals("table"))
      {
         testClass.tables[tableNumber].nodeNumber = numParagraphs;
         tableNumber++;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would just be to serialize the paragraph "index" of the table into your XML at the time of serialization. That way you wouldn't have to do anything custom.

However, to do what you are looking for with the XmlSerializer you could handle the deserialization yourself for certain element types using the UnknownElement event. Notice that the XmlElement attributes have been removed from the test class in order for the table and paragraph elements to be handled.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace XMLDeserializeTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static int paragraphCount = 0;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string file = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\test.xml";

            paragraphCount = 0;
            test testClass = Deserialize(file);

        }

        static test Deserialize(string url)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(test));
            serializer.UnknownElement += serializer_UnknownElement;
            StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(url);
            return serializer.Deserialize(stream) as test;
        }

        static void serializer_UnknownElement(object sender, XmlElementEventArgs e)
        {            
            test t = (test)e.ObjectBeingDeserialized;

            if (e.Element.Name == "table")
            {
                var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Table));
                var sr = new StringReader(e.Element.OuterXml);
                Table newTable = s.Deserialize(sr) as Table;               
                newTable.nodeNumber = paragraphCount;
                t.tables.Add(newTable);                
            }
            else if (e.Element.Name == "paragraph")
            {
                String paragraphText = e.Element.InnerText;
                t.paragraphs.Add(paragraphText);
                paragraphCount++;
            }
        }

    }

    public class test
    {
        public List<string> paragraphs { get; set; }
        public List<Table> tables { get; set; }

        public test()
        {

        }

    }

    [Serializable, XmlRoot("table")]
    public class Table
    {
        [XmlElement("row")]
        public List<Row> rows { get; set; }

        public int nodeNumber { get; set; }  // This is what needs to be tracked

        public Table()
        {

        }
    }

    [Serializable, XmlRoot("row")]
    public class Row
    {
        [XmlElement("entry")]
        public List<string> entries { get; set; }

        public Row()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great.  Did not know you can interrupt deserialization and then continue after processing a special case, or that you could deserialize just one element.  I was dreading having to manually deserialize the multiple levels contained in my actual table element.